# XML parsing error: 'A string literal was expected' when inserting values into table

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, insert

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008 I am attempting to insert values into an sql table with the columns **type_id of datatype int** and **xml_info of datatype XML**. I am using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_applied_devices ([type_id],[xml_info])
VALUES (1,'<Profile ID=99><Server><ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>  <Name>localhost</Name><Services></Services></Server></Profile>')
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Msg 9413, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 13, A string literal was expected

What am I doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:**
I found that the source of the error is the xml element's ID attribute, `<Profile ID=99>` seems to be what is causing the error. How can I correctly insert xml with an attribute ? Do I need to somehow escape one of the characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XML documents are **text**ual by nature.  This is not HTML for a web page, so you need ALL attribute values in quotes (single or double).

```
INSERT INTO tbl_applied_devices ([type_id],[xml_info])
VALUES (1,'<Profile ID="99"><Server><ID>BC4A18CA-AFB5-4268-BDA9-C990DAFE7783</ID>  <Name>localhost</Name><Services></Services></Server></Profile>')
```

It's very hard to parse the [XML 1.0 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) but here's a Microsoft version for [.Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256152.aspx), which is just as relevant for SQL Server XML.

Comment: I too have noticed that it seems much easier to parse XML than it is to parse the XML specification.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Attributes, ID is an attribute, must be quoted. Try ID="99"